# cannot be filtered in query call

Tags: trigger

I wrote a rollup trigger where i apply condition in query(where Description__c!=null) then I got an error-  Description__c field cannot be filtered in query call. Please help

Trigger

```
trigger NewProductsInfoRollup on Products_Info__c (after insert,after delete,after undelete) {
    List<id> accIdList = new List<id>();
    //List<string> stringList = new List<string>();

    if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUndelete){
        for(Products_Info__c proInfo : Trigger.new){
            accIdList.add(proInfo.Merchant_Name__c);
        }    
    }
    if(Trigger.isDelete){
        for(Products_Info__c proInfo : Trigger.old){
            accIdList.add(proInfo.Merchant_Name__c);
        }
    }
    List<Account> accUpdateList = new List<Account>();
    For(Account acc : [SELECT WebStore_Products_Uploaded__c,WebStore_Product_Descriptions__c,
                        (SELECT id,Description__c 
                          FROM Products_Info__r where Description__c!=null) 
                        FROM Account WHERE id =: accIdList]){
        acc.WebStore_Products_Uploaded__c = acc.Products_Info__r.size();  
        acc.WebStore_Product_Descriptions__c = acc.Products_Info__r.size();
        accUpdateList.add(acc);
    }
    try{
        update accUpdateList;
    }Catch(Exception e){
        System.debug('Exception :'+e.getMessage());
    }    
}
```

Comment: What datatype is your `Description__c` field? I have a feeling it's some variant of `Textarea`, which is not filterable in queries.

Comment: yeah, it's Long Text Area(32768) datatype.

Answer (score 1):

The various `Textarea` field types cannot be used to filter a query (i.e. in the `WHERE` clause). [Here's the relevant documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/field_types.htm#i1435887).

As an additional note, using the not equals operator in your `WHERE` clause will mean that your inner query must perform a table scan, slowing it down.

If there's another field in `Products_Info__c` that you can filter by, I'd strongly consider using it.

If detecting a blank/null `Description__c` is your only option, then you'll have to take a different approach.

The first one that comes to mind is to create a new checkbox field on `Products_Info__c`, which I'll call `Has_Description__c`.

- Set the default for the field to `FALSE`
- Create a new workflow rule

  - set it to evaluate `When a record is created, and every time it's edited`
  - make the criteria a formula `NOT(ISBLANK(Description__c))`
  - set the null handling to `Treat blanks as blanks`.
- Create a new workflow field update to set `Has_Description__c` to true

If you wish, you can create another workflow rule and field update to put `Has_Description__c` back to `FALSE` if `Description__c` becomes null.

After adding the workflow rule(s), you'll need to cause the new workflow to run to make `Has_Description__c` contain accurate information. You can do this by executing anonymous apex (through the developer console, or your IDE if it supports it), or by using the Data Loader.

Once that's all done you can simply update your existing query, replacing `Description__c != null` with `Has_Description__c = true`

Comment: or, given that the query is being executed in APEX, the filtering could be done on the retrieved SObjects using APEX `if` statement.